Using store.dispatch in a Cypress test causes a webpack loader error
I am trying to use store dispatch in a Cypress test but I have a webpack loader error...
I'm using craco with react 18.2 and cypress 13.14.2
my config :
index.ts
if ((window as any).Cypress) {
  (window as any).store = store;
}

craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react',
                '@babel/preset-typescript',
              ],
            },
          },
          'ts-loader',
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      });

      webpackConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx');

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: require('craco-cesium')(),
    },
  ],
};

cypress.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import conf from './craco.config.js';
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'create-react-app',
      bundler: 'webpack',
      webpackConfig: conf,
    },
  },
});

and finally the error when I use npx cypress open and chose my e2e test
my test:
  cy.window().then((win: any) => {
    const store = win.store;

    // check if store is actif
    expect(store).to.exist; // passed ok
    expect(store.dispatch).to.exist; // passed ok

    cy.window()
      .its('store')
      .invoke('dispatch', mailshotsActions.setUpdatingQuill(true)); // loader error

Error

Error: Webpack Compilation Error Module parse failed: Unexpected token
(118:16) File was processed with these loaders:  *
../../../Library/Caches/Cypress/13.14.2/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these
loaders. |
setEnvironmentSelectedCategory(defaultEnvironmentSelectedCategory); |
};

    return (<ctx.Provider value={{ |                 inputTab: inputTab, |                 setInputTab: setInputTab,


Module parse failed: Unexpected token (42:12) File was processed with
these loaders:  *
../../../Library/Caches/Cypress/13.14.2/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these
loaders. |         } |     };

return (<GenericModalBackground_1.default modalType={modalType} hasExtendWidth={hasExtendWidth}> |       <div


className={[genericModal_module_scss_1.default.modalContainer,
className].join(' ')} data-cy={dataCy}> |         {actionType !==
GenericModalActionEnum.OK &&
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an
appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
configured to process this file. See
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for this
binary file)
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) You may need an
appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
configured to process this file. See
https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

@import '../../theme/main';
...


